# How to integrate SAPUI5 apps developed on ABAP repository in HANA Cloud Platform

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

The scenario is to use **already developed SAPUI5 applications on ABAP Gateway** as portal widgets in sites developed through SAP HANA Cloud Platform,portal service.

I know we can add the ABAP backend gateway services using HANA Cloud connector and destination in HCP cockpit.

How to do we deal with the SAPUI5 applications.

a) Do we need to export them from the ABAP repository and import them into HCP web ide?

b) Can we directly deploy the same application on HCP as well and access it on the site?

In above both cases, what about the service calls made from within the app? wouldn't the urls be changed once the app is moved/imported to HCP [assuming app only makes call to relative urls.]

Any information/Documentation on this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to both a) and b) my answer is Yes. With some reservation for a) as actually I just don't know of another method to deploy existing SAPUI5 apps from backend to HCP.

In my case the scenario was the following:

First, we installed HCP connector, linked it to existing S-users, then I defined a destination in my HCP account. Be aware that you have to add some specific attributes to the destination to make it available in WebIDE.

My task was to extend some existing SAPUI5 applications, so I imported them into WebIDE and it appeared that they worked just fine when running via WebIDE without changing a single line of code or configuration. Apparently they can be deployed to HCP as a standalone apps or as a part of Fiori launchpad.